# List out all the registered component in container , Windsor?

Tags: components, castle-windsor, containers, resolve

I got this exception when tried to instantiate a component using factory.

```
Requested component named '<component_Name>' was not found in the container. Did you forget to register it?

There is one other component supporting requested service '<service_Name>'. Is it what you were looking for?
```

component  is registered in the container ( as it is returns the instance using resolve method). it likes some dependency component is not register which causes this exception. so i tried look at all the component and service installed in container but don't know how to do that.
is there any procedure which will list out all the service/components registered in the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via [debugger views](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Debugger-views.ashx)

Comment: Anyway, it helps :), Tqx @rarous

Comment: @X.L.Ant how does it not answer the question? It is a terse, straight to the point answer exactly providing what was asked. If that's not a good answer, I don't know what is.

Comment: I didn't write this comment, maybe the review system put it there for me as I reviewed this answer (that I don't remember flagging as "not an answer", but I may be wrong). Anyway, it's a answer indeed. I'll remove my comment. Sorry.